# Delphi - Easily update your application : the use of packages

Tags: delphi, package, updates

I would like to break down my application into smaller bits, for two reasons:

- easier code reusability and maintenance
- simplification for users to update to a newer version

My application EXE (debug version) is about 30 Mb in size, and as I've been advised a few times, I don't need to have all 20+ forms created at runtime.

Furthermore, my application is naturally divided in "functionality groups", so I decided, with the help of [this article](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178), to go for packages.

I try to build a new test application with this in mind.

Now, my EXE size is down to 3 Mb, and I have a couple of packages that load, create, and destroy my secondary forms on demand. The application is fast, and would only require the user to download a small package when a part of the application has been updated or enhanced.

My only problem at this stage is, I am unable to "share" my data module between packages.

The last part of the article I linked earlier is about that, but I did not quite understand it, and the `FDConnection` that resides on the DataModule (created and loaded with the Main Form at runtime) does not "propagate" (not sure this is the correct terminology) to my packages when they are loaded.

Could someone explain how to achieve that? Loading packages when needed, and using a centralized DataModule for them all?

Comment: You can certainly share the DataModule across package boundaries, but you have to do so manually.  You just have to make sure that the EXE and any packages that use the DataModule are using the same DataModule *unit* (which means moving the DataModule itself into a package that the EXE and other packages can then link to), and then you can propagate the DataModule *object* by having the EXE create it at runtime and pass it to any loaded package that needs it.

Comment: "Easier code reusability and maintenance" does not in any way require the use of packages. In fact the opposite is more true; because there are number of things to watch out for when using packages. Good design, clean code and a solid approach to testing all lead to easier code reusability and maintenance. ***None*** of these things mandate the use of packages. As for "simplification for users to update to a newer version" ... What makes you think multiple package files, _ensuring **compatibility** between each package_, is easier to deploy than a ***single*** exe? (No matter how large it is.)

Comment: In short, your justification for why you want to use packages is unsound. There are reasons to use packages; but if you use the wrong tool (approach) for whatever your goals may be - you'll make your life unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @CraigYoung : I though using packages was the solution to smaller updates downloads and this is why I tried this way. As you said, and as Remy's tip made me realize, this approach is far beyond my reach considering my level of Delphi knowledge. So there is no other way to distribute and update than sending the new exe file ? No "small patch" you could send ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it appears that this approach is far beyond my reach at the moment, and that I am probably trying this for the wrong reasons. Thanks anyway

Comment: Tip: My newest software, I just added an auto-update feature, which simply downloads a *full* installer package for the *entire* software. It's over 50MB, and downloads in about 20-30 seconds, remotely. Modern computers / internet are fast enough to accommodate. My general rule of thumb is, if your equipment can't handle downloading the full installer, then it can't handle much of anything else. Now obviously, much larger applications do require some separation. For such a thing, I find DLLs more useful, but of course also requires more meticulous design.

Comment: @JerryDodge : Thanks again for the advise. I'll stick to the "1 exe file" dev type.

Comment: Just to add, Plex Media Server does the exact same thing, and that's quite a large system.

Comment: @Mathmathou "_I thought using packages was the solution to smaller updates downloads_". First, that's quite a bit different from "simpler for users to update". You would have the complication of figuring out what the user already has installed so that you only download what's necceasry. This is a dependency headache if you get it wrong. But more importantly, it's not even true if any of your packages have changed... The linker ensures you final EXE only has the dependencies it actually references, but packages must include things you don't need at all. I.e. Bigger total size for full install.

Comment: If you really want smaller downloads, you best bet is having a comprehensive download/update framework that figures out the delta that needs to be download and updates only what's changed. Note this approach is even possible with single EXE by figuring out a binary diff that can be patched into the local EXE file. However, the question is: _Is such complexity really worth the effort and risks?_

Comment: @Craig, on the other hand, I cannot imagine how e.g. a complex CRM would be distributed as a single binary file. You would distribute all the modules, even those the customer doesn't need and haven't paid for. Not speaking about the final size of such file. I mean, I think there are still cases when some modularity takes place (and if you have your app. modular, you are quite close for plugin support e.g.).

Comment: @Victoria Please don't mistake me. I'm not in any way questioning the use multiple files (binary or otherwise) - they certainly are useful to solve the ***right*** problem. I'm questioning OP's specific motivation, where packages would actually have entirely the opposite effect of what he desires. Also, bear in mind that **modularisation** doesn't _require_ packages. Simply good design with _modular_ units provides that -  regardless of how many files make up the distribution. (Personally I suspect OP started to encounter maintainability issues, and his initial research led to an XY problem).

Comment: If the aim is smaller updates, you can always achieve this with a diff patcher tool.

Comment: @CraigYoung - lol, this could have very well been the case but, even with 20 + forms, my application is quite simple and all features are mostly independent from each other. No, the idea was that, because I'm in beta stage, I correct some bugs, add new features on requests of my users and I wanted to spare them the full download each time. One of my friends (who codes in C#) releases patches that are 500Ko max and I wanted to do the same. A search lead me to packages and here I am. But, as you mentioned, this is probably not the solution. Thanks for your good advises, as always.